# Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(intermediate value)' as it is undefined error in Next JS & Graph QL

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, graphql, next.js

I'm trying to achieve a Apollo request to SpaceX api. But getting a ​500 (Internal Server Error) and also at getStaticProps. I don't know if it's a syntax issue or some error in my method of usage.

Note: API is used in postman and it works fine there.

Please help me. Thank you !

```
  import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, gql, ApolloError } from "@apollo/client";
  import Head from "next/head";
   import Image from "next/image";
  import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

   export default function Home({ launches }) {
  console.log(launches, "data");
```

UI layer as usual from Next JS

```
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>
          Welcome to <a href="https://nextjs.org">Next.js!</a>
        </h1>

        <p className={styles.description}>
          Get started by editing{" "}
          <code className={styles.code}>pages/index.js</code>
        </p>

        <div className={styles.grid}>
          <a href="https://nextjs.org/docs" className={styles.card}>
            <h2>Documentation &rarr;</h2>
            <p>Find in-depth information about Next.js features and API.</p>
          </a>

          <a href="https://nextjs.org/learn" className={styles.card}>
            <h2>Learn &rarr;</h2>
            <p>Learn about Next.js in an interactive course with quizzes!</p>
          </a>

          <a
            href="https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples"
            className={styles.card}
          >
            <h2>Examples &rarr;</h2>
            <p>Discover and deploy boilerplate example Next.js projects.</p>
          </a>

          <a
            href="https://vercel.com/new?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
            className={styles.card}
          >
            <h2>Deploy &rarr;</h2>
            <p>
              Instantly deploy your Next.js site to a public URL with Vercel.
            </p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </main>

      <footer className={styles.footer}>
        <a
          href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Powered by{" "}
          <span className={styles.logo}>
            <Image src="/vercel.svg" alt="Vercel Logo" width={72} height={16} />
          </span>
        </a>
      </footer>
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {
  console.log("ran func data from spacex");

  const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: "https://api.spacex.land/graphql/",
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });

  const { data } = await client
    .query({
      query: gql`{
          launchesPast(limit: 1) {
            mission_name
            launch_date_local
            launch_site {
              site_name_long
            }
            links {
              article_link
              video_link
            }
            rocket {
              rocket_name
              first_stage {
                cores {
                  flight
                  core {
                    reuse_count
                    status
                  }
                }
              }
              second_stage {
                payloads {
                  payload_type
                  payload_mass_kg
                  payload_mass_lbs
                }
              }
            }
            ships {
              name
              home_port
              image
            }
          }
        }
      `,
    })
    .then((res) => console.log(res))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err, "error on your side"));

  console.log("ran func data from spacex");

  return {
    props: {
      launches: data
    },
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two things going on here. First, you're not returning the response in your `then` statement so `data` is undefined. So you need to change this to:

```js
const { data } = await client
  .query({
    query: gql`
      { ... }
    `,
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
    return res
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err, "error on your side")
    return err
  })
```

Without this, your `then` statement is capturing the response and returning the console log statement to `const {data}` which is a problem because `data` is not defined on `console.log`.

Once you fix that, you may run into another error, this time from SpaceX - `query exceeds complexity limit`. This isn't so much a problem with your code but with the number of data points and depth of information you're trying to pull from the api. I can't tell you how to fix that one because it depends on your business rules, but once you solve it, you should see data flowing.